# How to add multiple headers to Windows Phone WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, webbrowser-control

How do you add headers to the Windows Phone web browser control? I want to add two headers, `fore` and `back`. Right now I add one header by using this:

```
browser.Navigate(newUrl, null, "fore:red");
```

See [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626636%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

But how would would I separate two headers? The third parameter of the `Navigate` method is called extraHeaders which implies more than one, but I don't know how to separate them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer from Microsoft can be found here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172998
and it tells that the separator is a carriage return '\n'

Comment: Thank you for the link to that article. (Not that I would have known that chr$(13) means New Line)

Answer (score 2):

I kept guessing and eventually figured out the separator character was a new line. ("\n"). No help from Microsoft's documentation. Now my code is something like:

```
 browser.Navigate(newUrl, null, "fore:red\nback:blue");
```